# trying to update state when clicked

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I have the following which I am trying to update to true to false when a user clicks on a button.

However it's not working keeps throwing

```
TypeError: _this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState(function (state) {
        return {
          icon: !state.icon
        };
      })', '_this.setState' is an instance of Object)
```

My code to action this is

```
 handleClick = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        
        this.setState((state) => {
          return { icon: !state.icon };
        });
    }
```

It is meant to talk to

```
export default class Mediaplayer extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: [],
            station:null,
            icon: false,
         };
    }
```

FULL CODE

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import Image from 'next/image';
import { Container, Card, Row, Col, DropdownButton, Dropdown, ProgressBar } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { PlayCircle, PauseCircle } from 'react-bootstrap-icons';



export default class Mediaplayer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            error: null,
            isLoaded: false,
            items: [],
            station:null,
            icon: false,
         };
    }
   
     

    
    componentDidMount() {
        const token = uuidv4();
        // alert("hello");
        if(!sessionStorage['uuid']){
            sessionStorage.setItem("uuid",token);
        }
        console.log(token);
        if(!sessionStorage['station']){
            sessionStorage.setItem("station","DRN1");
        }
      
        if(!sessionStorage['live']){
            sessionStorage.setItem("live",true);
        }

        this.setState = {
            station: "https://example.com/station/DRN1?uuid="+sessionStorage['uuid']
        }

        document.getElementById("player").src= "https://example.com/station/"+sessionStorage['station']+"?uuid="+sessionStorage['uuid'];
        document.getElementById("player").muted = true;
        document.getElementById("player").play();

      setInterval(() => {
        this.nowplaying();
      }, 30000);
    
      this.mediamute();
    }

    mediamute(){
        var myAudio = document.getElementById('player');
        document.getElementById('player').dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("click",{bubbles: true, cancellable: true}));
        document.getElementById('player').click();
        if (myAudio.duration) {
            console.log("playing")
            setTimeout(function(){
            
            document.getElementById("player").muted = false;
            document.getElementById("player").play();
            }
            , 10000)
         }
         else{
             console.log("NOT PLAYING")
             setTimeout(this.mediamute,2000);
         }
    }


    nowplaying(){
       console.log("running now playing info")
         fetch("https://example.com:9000/nowplaying/"+sessionStorage.station+"?uuid="+sessionStorage['uuid'])
         
         .then(res => res.json())
         .then((result) => {
             console.log(result)
             document.getElementById("Now_Playing_Artist").innerHTML = result.data[0].track.artist;
             document.getElementById("Now_Playing_Title").innerHTML = result.data[0].track.title;
             //document.getElementById("Now_Playing_Cover").src = result.data[0].track.imageurl;
             document.getElementById("Now_Playing_Cover").srcset = result.data[0].track.imageurl;
         
         }
         )
  
    }
    
  
    handleClick(){
       /* this.setState(prevState => ({
          icon: !prevState.icon
        }));*/
        this.setState({ //the error happens here
            icon: true
        });
    };
    


    render(){
        const { station, icon } = this.state;
      
       //  var streamurl = icyStream;//window.com_adswizz_synchro_decorateUrl(icyStream); 
            console.log(station);
            return  <div className="mediaplayerbg">
                            <Container fluid="sm">
                                <Row className="justify-content-md-center">
                                    <Col lg={1} xs={2}>
                                        <Image id="Now_Playing_Cover" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/radiomedia-images/station_logos/DRN1Logo.png" width="60" height="60"/>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col lg={3} xs={7}>
                                        <Row id="Now_Playing_Artist">ARTIST</Row>
                                        <Row id="Now_Playing_Title">SONG</Row>
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col lg={1} xs={2} id="mediaControl" >
                                     <i className='large material-icons' onClick={this.handleClick}>
                                            { icon ? 'play_circle_outline' : 'pause_circle_outline'}</i>
                                    </Col>
                                  
                                </Row>
                            </Container>
                                                 
                            <audio id="player" src={station}  controls={true} hidden={true}/>
                    </div>
    }

}
```

**Note this is only a component inside a nextjs app.**
I am wondering if this is more a nextjs issue since it only seems to happen in the nextjs application.

Comment: don't use arrow funcitons

Comment: please explain? @DedaDev

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-basic-class-component-forked-6m6wo?file=/src/index.js

it still work ? what is your problem

Comment: @AnhTuan I tried that - maybe it's because we also use NextJS ?

Comment: I don't think next is your problem try to remove a part of your code until this error disappear

Comment: The error I am getting now is 

```
TypeError: _this.setState is not a function. (In '_this.setState(function (state) {
        return {
          icon: !state.icon
        };
      })', '_this.setState' is an instance of Object)
```

Comment: @RussellHarrower You should set the state as `this.setState({ station: "..." })` in `componentDidMount`. As it stands, you're overriding the `setState` function, hence why you're seeing that error.

Comment: @juliomalves so your saying to move onClick function inside the componentDidMount?

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying to change the syntax on how you're trying to set the state inside `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. first when you use the arrow function you get the current value so when you do set state and set it to the current value in the state so nothing will happend.

```js
      this.setState(state => ({
              cart: [...state.cart, product.name],
              total: state.total + product.price
            }))
```

this is how you update with arrow function

2. I don't know what you have in the component but I recommend  you to use Function Component because handling state changes is much more easy

```js
    const [state,setState] = useState(0);
    setState(3)
```

Comment: I can't use function component. Otherwise I would. the above code 1. does not work either.

Comment: @RussellHarrower why you can't use because the componentDidMount? and what is the error
i ask this becasue the only thing that can keep you in class is componentDidMount
and useEffect can mimk it

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `this.handleClick` in the component constructor.

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
     //do something wih prevState
    }));
  }
```

Comment: I tried that and it does not work

  handleClick(){
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          icon: !prevState.icon
        }));
    };

Comment: You are getting the same error? Can you post the code of your whole component?